# Efficient method to evaluate integrals with multiple roots in denominator

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt{(x^2 + \beta x +1 )} \sqrt{(x^2 + \alpha x +1 )}} dx $$

I saw this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641739/method-for-evaluating-integrals-with-squared-roots-in-denominator) but I don't think the methods in answers are much applicable here.

**My attempt**:

$$ \int \frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt{(x + \frac{\beta}{2})^2  + ( 1 - \frac{\beta^2}{4} )} \sqrt{(x + \frac{\alpha}{2})^2  + ( 1 - \frac{\alpha^2}{4} )}} dx= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1- \frac{\beta^2}{4} } \sqrt{1- \frac{\alpha^2}{4} }}\int \frac{x^2-1}{x\sqrt{\frac{(x + \frac{\beta}{2})^2}{ ( 1 - \frac{\beta^2}{4} )}  +1} \sqrt{\frac{(x + \frac{\alpha}{2})^2}{ ( 1 - \frac{\alpha^2}{4} )}  +1}} dx
$$

Not sure what's the best way to go now..

Answer (score 3):

Divide both numerator and denominator by $x^2$

$$\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}{\sqrt{(x+\beta +\frac{1}{x})}\sqrt{(x+\alpha +\frac{1}{x})}}dx$$

which immediately suggests using the substitution $t=x+\frac{1}{x}$

$$\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{\left(t+\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right)^2}} = \cosh^{-1}\left[\frac{t+\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}{\left|\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right|}\right]$$

from a simple hyperbolic substitution. This makes the final answer

$$\cosh^{-1}\left[\frac{x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}{\left|\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\right|}\right]$$